# Meager set and disjoint with line $y=ax$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, set-theory, descriptive-set-theory, transfinite-induction

**Lemma.** Let $X$ and $Y$ be second countable. If $A\subset X$ and $B\subset Y$, then $A\times B$ is meager iff at least of $A,B$ is meager.

Assume $f\colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ and $D$ be a meager set subset of $R.$ Consider the graph of $f$ on $D$, that is. $$W:=\{\langle x, f(x)\rangle\colon \  x\in D\setminus\{0\}\}$$  By lemma above $W$ is meager in $\mathbb R^2$. Now, $\mathbb R^2\setminus W$ is co-meager in $\mathbb R^2$. I want to find a line $\ell_a(x)=ax$ such that $\ell_a\cap W=\{\langle x,ax\rangle\ \colon \  x\in\mathbb R\}\cap W=\emptyset.$  Is it possible in  $\text ZFC$? Do we need a set-theortical assumption, like the union of less than continuum many meager set will not cover $\mathbb R.$ Any help will be apprciacted greatly

Comment: Don't you mean that you want the intersection of $\ell_a$ and $W$ to be empty? You've defined $W$ so that $(0,0)\notin W$.

Comment: Also, it's clearly irrelevant that $W$ is the graph of a sum of two functions. Why not just ask the question for the graph of an arbitrary function?

Comment: There is no reason to look at two functions: you’re really just interested in the graph of the single function $f+g$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman, you are right. you can even say a subset meager of $\mathbb R^2$. Is it possible or not

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, yes , one function is enough. even a meager set of $\mathbb R^2$. Is it possibel or not

Comment: @BrianM.Scott@Alex, I edited the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not necessarily possible. Let $D$ be a meagre subset of $\Bbb R$ of cardinality $2^\omega$, e.g., the middle-thirds Cantor set. Then we can index $D=\{x_a:a\in\Bbb R\}$ by the real numbers. Now let

$$f:D\to\Bbb R:x_a\mapsto ax_a\;;$$

then the graph of $f$ meets every line $\ell_a$ through the origin.

Comment: And by a similar trick, you can hit every line of the form $y = ax + b$: put the pairs $(a,b)$ in bijection with $D$ and let $f$ map $x$ to $y$ such that $(x,y)$ is on the line corresponding to $x$ by the bijection.

Comment: @Brain M. Scott, No set -theoretical can made to make true ? what do you think ?

Comment: @00GB: No, because you just need to ‘kill off’ each of the $2^\omega$ lines through the origin, and you can always do it a point at a time. It’s a cardinality argument that doesn’t depend on any particular set-theoretic assumptions.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, do you mean " point at a time " do you mean construct a function such that this will happen? Could you please say more about it ? Thank you for you time

Comment: @00GB: The construction that I gave in my answer works in $\mathsf{ZFC}$; no additional set-theoretic hypothesis (e.g., the continuum hypothesis or Martin’s axiom) is going to affect it.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, If we replace the set in our construction by a set $D$ such that $|D|<\mathfrak c $, then we can find such a line . right ?

Comment: @00GB: Yes, by a straightforward cardinality argument.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118184/discussion-between-00gb-and-brian-m-scott).